# Bootstrap carousel image stops for a second

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using Bootstrap Carousel and everything is fine until the moment of sliding from the last image to first. When the first image is showing, end of the third is still on the first for a split second. You can check it on this adress:

https://youtu.be/cRb_cujsbBY

My carousel code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide container" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active" ></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="first-slide" src="/zrodla/zdjecia/baner-reklamowy.jpg" alt="First slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
            <h1 class="elo2">Ubezpieczenie OC i AC samochodu</h1>
            <p class="ps3">Czas wyruszyć w drogę..</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="second-slide" src="/zrodla/zdjecia/baner2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
            <h1 class="elo2" >Życie to najcenniejszy dar</h1>
            <p class="ps3">Zadbaj o nie</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="third-slide" src="/zrodla/zdjecia/baner3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
            <h1 class="elo2">Wszędzie dobrze ale w domu najlepiej </h1>
            <p class="ps3">Pakiet majątkowy z pewnością spełni twoje oczekiwania</p>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `style="width:100%;` at the end of each `<img>` tag

Like this:

```
 <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="first-slide" src="/zrodla/zdjecia/baner-reklamowy.jpg" alt="First slide" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
        ...
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: With respect to Bootstrap 4, this should be achieved by applying `d-block w-100` to the `<img>` tag, per Bootstrap's documentation on the Carousel component.

Comment: @Robert C: Yes..we can do that too! Thanks for pointing that out!